# running a python script on server

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

i have a python script on the server

```
#!/usr/bin/env  python
import cgi
import cgitb; #cgitb.enable()
import sys, os
from subprocess import call
import time
import subprocess
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

component = form.getvalue('component')
command = form.getvalue('command')

success = True

print """Content-Type: text/html\n"""

if component=="Engine" and command=="Start":
    try:
         process = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/sbin/telepath','engine','start'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
         print "{ans:12}" 
    except Exception, e:
         success = False
         print "{ans:0}"
```

When I run this script and add the component and command parameters to be "Engine" and "Start" respectively - it starts the process and prints to the shell

```
"""Content-Type: text/html\n"""
{ans:12}
```

but most importantly - it starts the process!

however, when I run the script by POSTing to it, it returns {ans:12} but does not run the process which was the whole intention in the first place. Any logical explanation?

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: Maybe you need to wait for the subprocess' running is finished. Add `process.communicate()` before `print "{ans:12}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's one of two things, firstly your process is probably running but your `python` code doesn't handle the output so do:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/sbin/telepath','engine','start'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print process.stdout.read()
```

This is the most likely and explains why you see the output from the command line and not the browser, or secondly because the script is run through the browsers as the user `apache` and not with your `userid` check the permission for `/usr/sbin/telepath`.

Comment: i do see the output on my browser though..It's just that if I run the script from my browser by invoking POST to it the process doesn't start even though it appears to invoke the popen()

Comment: I will check the permissions issue though :-(